# How to get the active/selected QRadioButton from QTableView

Tags: python, python-3.x, qtableview, pyside2, qradiobutton

I want to get the active QRadioButton from the QTableView when clicking a button. But I don't know how to do it.

Let's say I have a csv file **my_csv** that contains

```
ANIMAL; AGE
DOG; 3
CAT; 5
COW; 5
```

This is my sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView, QRadioButton, QPushButton

my_button = QPushButton()
model = QStandardItemModel()
view = QTableView()
view.setModel(model)

df = pd.read_csv(my_csv, sep=';')
header = list(['']) + df.columns
model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header)

for index in df_interface.index:
    data = list()
    item = QStandardItem()
    data.append(item)
    items = [QStandardItem("{}".format(field)) for field in df.iloc[index]]
    [element.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignHCenter) for element in items]
    data.extend(items)
    model.appendRow(data)
    view.setIndexWidget(self.model.index(index, 0), QRadioButton())
```

Comment: What do you mean *active QRadioButton*? And when do you want to get it?

Comment: I want to get the selected _QRadioButton_ when pressing the _my_button_ see the edited version

Comment: What do you mean by "selected QRadioButton"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "active", you mean the currently checked radio-button (if any). If so, one way to solve this is to use a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html), like this:

```
# create button group
radio_btns = QButtonGroup()

for index in df_interface.index:
    ...
    # add button to the button group
    button = QRadioButton()
    radio_btns.addButton(button, index)
    view.setIndexWidget(self.model.index(index, 0), button)
```

With that done, you can get the index of the checked button like this:

```
index = radio_btns.checkedId()
```

(But note that this will return `-1` if there is currently no checked button).